# Qt, QML пустое окно

Tags: qt, qml

Не могу  понять почему  не работает?

Делаю  задачку  на QML и нужно передать путь  к файлу  в  main.cpp, передаю так:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view;
    view.setTitle("Proga");
    view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("StartMenu.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

но выводится пустое  окно. Файл StartMenu.qml  находится в корне папки с программой.

Подскажите как сделать чтобы  работало?

Comment: `QApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/StartMenu.qml"`

Comment: так Вы имеете введу?                                                                                                          
                     int main(int argc, char *argv[])                                                                           {
                QApplication app(argc, argv);
                QApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/StartMenu.qml";

                return app.exec();
                 }'

Comment: Там, где в quickview подается код qml-компонента: `view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/StartMenu.qml"));`

Comment: @Bearded Beaver, так и выводится пустое окно и пишет: QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
file:///D:/Misc/build-Program-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug/debug/StartMenu.qml: File not found

Comment: Я правильно понял, что файл qml лежит в корневой папке с исполняемым файлом, а не с кодом программы? Путь, где программа пытается найти файл, указан. Он там лежит фактически?

Comment: @Bearded Beaver,  нет  у меня есть папка: program а  в ней все файлы: .cpp, .qml, .h

Comment: Если qml не может меняться на лету пользователем, то его надо поместить в ресурс и обращаться у нему через ресурс. Если предполагается, что пользователь или администратор может заменить qml без участия программиста, qml нужно класть в папку относительно исполняемого файла

Comment: @Bearded Beaver, в ресурс и обращаться у нему через ресурс - через qrc?  qml нужно класть в папку относительно исполняемого файла  - debug?

Comment: да, делаем qrc файл, в него помещаем qml (можно все qml файлы, которые используются в приложении), к файлу обращаемся `:/path/to.qml`. Чтобы не ошибиться, в редакторе ресурсов в QtCreator есть пункт что-то вроде copy path to recource to clipboard. Qml файлы в этом случае лежат в папке с кодом, там же лежит и файл ресурсов. При деплое приложения ресурсы будут "вкомпилировны" в исполняемый файл

Comment: @Bearded Beaver, а можно без qrc сделать как то ?

Comment: Можно, тогда кладем qml файл рядом с исполняемым файлом программы и пишем путь как я показал в первом комментарии

Comment: сделал  два варианта, и оба  пустое окно открывается. Второй вариант скинул файл в  дебаг., там у меня exe.

Comment: в  обоих случаях выводит такое: QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
QQuickView only supports loading of root objects that derive from QQuickItem. 

If your example is using QML 2, (such as qmlscene) and the .qml file you 
loaded has 'import QtQuick 1.0' or 'import Qt 4.7', this error will occur. 

To load files with 'import QtQuick 1.0' or 'import Qt 4.7', use the 
QDeclarativeView class in the Qt Quick 1 module.                                            я использую import QtQuick 2.2

Comment: Теперь файл увиделся программой корректно, но в самом qml файле есть какая-то проблема. Приложите код qml

Comment: @Bearded Beaver  import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
Window
{
    width: 360
    height: 360
    Text
    {width: 125
        height: 73
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: qsTr("Hellow")
        font.family: "Times New Roman"
        font.pointSize: 26
        anchors.verticalCenterOffset: -74
        anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: -14
    }
 
    Button
        {text: "Start"
            x: 137
            y: 205
            width: 78
            height: 23
            onClicked: Qt.quit();
        }
    }
 }

Comment: @Вова, код лучше добавлять в текст вопроса (нажав [edit]), а не в комментарий, где он малочитабелен.

Answer (score 1):

Добавить StartMenu.qml в qrc. Для этого в Qt Creator жмём по проекту->добавить новый->файл ресурсов qt. По новому файлу жмём ПКМ, добавить существующий и выбираем StartMenu.qml. 
Далее открываем qml так:

```
viewer.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/qml/qmlchart/main.qml"));
```